# Optimizing memory usage of large Redis Hash and Sorted set

Tags: nosql, redis, in-memory-database, in-memory, memory-optimization

As part of a distributed crawler, we store all URLs in a **Redis sorted set**, which is the crawl queue and **Redis hash** (to de-duplicate and mark visited URLs).

We have about 11M URLs for various domains that we wish to visit in a file, which occupies *506 MB of space on disk*.

However the same set of URLs when put in **Redis sorted set**, with decreasing priorities starting from integer 11M all the way to 0, takes 1.759 GB of RAM and the **Redis hash** from key: URL-> value: same URL, takes **2.048 GB of RAM space**.

The redis server is hosted in High-memory (17GB) Extra Large EC2 Instance in AWS.

I want to figure out what's causing the space bloat in Redis, could it be because of inefficient way of storing them or should we optimize for memory in a certain way to avoid the space bloat? Any suggestion towards improving the memory performance would be gr8. Thanks in advance for any help!

This is the redis info dump:

```
redis_version:2.4.14
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.6.3
process_id:739
uptime_in_seconds:329647
uptime_in_days:3
lru_clock:1603627
used_cpu_sys:9521.58
used_cpu_user:3165.06
used_cpu_sys_children:19535.11
used_cpu_user_children:126500.32
connected_clients:76
connected_slaves:0
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
used_memory:12794713864
used_memory_human:11.92G
used_memory_rss:13586632704
used_memory_peak:16575849280
used_memory_peak_human:15.44G
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.06
mem_allocator:jemalloc-2.2.5
loading:0
aof_enabled:0
changes_since_last_save:46321
bgsave_in_progress:1
last_save_time:1358213403
bgrewriteaof_in_progress:0
total_connections_received:1702
total_commands_processed:95112145
expired_keys:3488037
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:43443780
keyspace_misses:38945
pubsub_channels:2
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:3820832
vm_enabled:0
role:master
db0:keys=116,expires=25
```

Comment: you say that you use ordered set as a queue, this implies that after you visit a URL you remove it from the set, correct?

Comment: yes, once a URL is visited, its removed from the sorted set and marked as completed (integer value 1) in the hash

Comment: Use list instead of sorted set if you need a queue. Use set instead of a dictionary url->url. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004565/redis-10x-more-memory-usage-than-data/10008222#10008222

Comment: Totally agree with @DidierSpezia in this case. In fact I wrote a toolbox of Python-Queue like implementations backed by Redis. I implemented `Queue` in Redis List, but used Sorted Set for queues that always maintain unique items. See here for details https://github.com/woozyking/techies