# Redis Data Structures Using up a lot of memory

Tags: memcached, redis, in-memory-database, in-memory

I ran an experiment in Redis to test memory usage of large keys. I loaded **16 Million strings**
with **50-60 characters** (bytes), roughly taking **802 MB** on disk into a sorted set in Redis. It
used up (got bloated to) **3.12 GB of RAM** for this sorted set.

Then I loaded 16 Million **short strings** (10-12 characters) occupying 220 MB of space on disk 
into another sorted set which still used up **2.5 GB of RAM**. It is evident that the reduction 
in space usage on disk is quite high (~72% reduced), but the Redis sorted set still uses 
quite a significant amount of memory used by the large strings.

The same is the case with Redis hashes also (the short strings use up pretty much 80% of 
memory used by long strings). Does memory used by Redis data structures depend only on the 
number of elements in the data structure (sorted set or hash) and does not on the length of 
each element (which is natural to think so- **shorter strings=>lesser memory**)?

It'll be great if I can understand **why**

***16 Million long strings use up almost same space as 16 Million short strings***

in **sorted set**, and if there is anything I can do to reduce memory taken up by the short strings
(any memory optimization)?

Comment: A quick (non answer) analysis; the difference in data size is ~600MB and the difference in memory requirements is ~600m, so there seems to be a non string length dependent constant factor of about 2.3GB for the amount of strings you added.

Comment: Non-string length dependent factor does not seem to be constant, it does depend on the number of elements in the data structure, which is very bad, as it grows when the data structure grows big (more number of elements)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is similar to this one:
[Redis 10x more memory usage than data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004565/redis-10x-more-memory-usage-than-data/10008222#10008222)

Sorted set is the less memory efficient data structure of Redis. It is implemented as a dictionary plus a skip list. Both data structures involve a number of metadata and pointers (on a per item basis), whose size is higher than 10, 12, 50, or 60 bytes.

A 50 bytes difference in the size of your strings does not result in significant difference  in the global memory footprint, because most of the memory is used by pointers, metadata, and [internal fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29). Of course a larger difference would result in a larger impact.

To leverage memory optimizations, you need to split your data structures (as described in the above link). It is easier to do it with hash or set, and generally difficult (or not possible at all) for sorted sets.

Comment: Is there any change that can be made to Redis.conf that can help us? The metadata fields like array of pointers, redis object wrappers dont seem to be reducable. 

"Actual data themselves (each of them prefixed by 8 bytes for size and capacity)" Can we optimize on the prefixed 8 bytes  ( as we know the size of strings max 20 bytes )

Comment: No. All the memory optimizations are described there: http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization and they are only interesting when the objects are small (i.e. small hashes, small sets, small sorted sets, etc ...)