# Redis insertion to hash is VERY(!) slow?

Tags: c#, performance, redis, .net-4.5, servicestack.redis

I have a jagged array (`1M x 100`) of random numbers :

```
0   --->[ 100 random numbers]
1   --->[ 100 random numbers]
2   --->[ 100 random numbers]
..  --->[ 100 random numbers]
..  --->[ 100 random numbers]
1M  --->[ 100 random numbers]
```

Those `100 random numbers` are Images ID's which I need to map them to userId (which is `0..1M`)

I want to store them in Redis. ( [*via Hash since I know that Hashes are stored very efficiently in Redis — it's also how **instagram** used it in order to solve similar problem*](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs))

---

**The Jagged array :**

```
int b = 1000000;
int[ ][] Friends = new int[b][];
```

(All ok.)

**The initialization of random numbers :**

```
  for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
     Friends[i] = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(n => appRandom.Value.Next(1, b )).ToArray();
    }
```

(All ok.)

And here is How I use Redis Client to enter values : ([*I use 1000 buckets optimization method*](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization))

```
  using (IRedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient(host))
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < Friends.Length; i++)
         {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
             redisClient.SetEntryInHash("urn:buck>" + (i / 1000), Friends[i][j].ToString(),i.ToString());
         }
     }
```

**Problem :**

The *Insertion* phase( I don't care about the initialization time)— It is taking **over an hour**  now and still not at `25%` !

related info :

I have a powerful computer : (win 8 ) , Also added the `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />`

[image]

**Question :**

- What am I doing wrong and how can I make the insertion faster ?

*(related info : those 100 numbers are Images Id's which I need to map them to userId)*

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Your peformance bottleneck is probably related to the number of roundtrips between your application and the redis server. You need to use pipelining, or use concurrent connections, or both, in order to maximize the throughput.

See examples of pipelining usage at:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineTests.cs

Last point: Windows is certainly not the best platform to get the best performance from Redis, and C# not the best language to achieve very high throughput.

Comment: If the question is whether a typed client (i.e. using C# POCO types) supports also pipelining, I believe the answer is positive.

Comment: Much(!) faster. thank you. can you please reference me to concurrent connections example ? Also , I changed it to SETS and not Hash. (SETS in my testing are faster) - so why did instagram used hash and they got better result ?

Comment: Since servicestack.Redis is synchronous, you need multiple threads and 1 connection per thread to increase throughput with multiple connections. Instagram probably used hash to benefit from zipmap/list and reduce memory consumption. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004565/redis-10x-more-memory-usage-than-data/10008222#10008222